# android facebook login and check user id

Tags: android, facebook

I use facebook sdk on android and I want to check user ID(show for example userID on Toast)
I wrote some code which can to login on facebook now I want to when user is logined I want to show user id by toast

This is a my code,

```
    public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ChooseLocation.class);
        startActivity(in);

        Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                        try {
                            JSONObject me = new JSONObject(facebook
                                    .request("me"));
                            String id = me.getString("id");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                ChooseLocation.class);
                        startActivity(in);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {

                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function to get user information when he/she successfully logs in.

```
    public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                    // getting id of the user
                final String id = profile.getString("id");
                // getting name of the user
                final String name = profile.getString("name");


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

See `Log.d("Profile", response);` in LogCat. It returns Json.
I think this will help you out.

Comment: thank you and where i can to call this getProfileInformation function on my code ?

Comment: Anywhere inside onComplete(Bundle values)

Comment: thank you it working but i want to show user id another activity by intent.putextra, but my problem is when i click login putextra values is null (for example textview's settext is hello),but when i click back button and then click login program working at the moment

Comment: startActivity((new Intent(this, NewActivityName.class)).putExtra("ID",id));

Comment: thanks but i know how to use Intent but first time intent values is null ,but when i click  back and then click  button again then i can to show user id another activity

Comment: upload your project somewhere and give me the link. I'll see it!

Comment: thank you this is a my code please see it https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0vd33d4j05e8o2/LoginFacebook.java

Comment: Please put logs when you are starting another activity. and see id.getText().toString() retrives the correct value or not!

Comment: yes i know i also try this but first time   value is null and a second time value is  userid

Comment: Try Starting Activity from my function. If it still not works... I suggest you to use SharedPrefrence.

Comment: i removed boolean type and i have this problem  .please see my pic.i also try your solution (startActivity((new Intent(this, NewActivityName.class)).putExtra("ID",id)); this) but also i have this  problem .please see my pic http://postimg.org/image/pmzo1lb3j/